# Group By `status` and `user` field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have table structure like

`users(user_id, username);`

`feedback(id, customer_id, user_id, status)`

where `status` will be `['scheduled', 'failed', 'cancelled']`;

I want result like

```
| Username  | scheduled count   | failed count  | cancelled count   |
|---------- |-----------------  |-------------- |-----------------  |
| Sarah     | 10                | 5             | 2                 |
| Alex      | 8                 | 7             | 5                 |
```

I tried a lot but failed to getting the result via `group by` clause.
It gives result on the basis on username but not status.

I tried some queries

```
sql> select users.username, count(*) as cal
from feedback
join users on users.user_id = feedback.user_id
group by feedback.user_id, feedback.status
```

```
sql> select users.username, count(*) as cal
from feedback
join users on users.user_id = feedback.user_id
group by feedback.user_id
```

etc.

Comment: Show us some attempts please

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would help.

Comment: I got downvote for the question, don't know why. I searched a lot, but enable to findout the same scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
select u.username,
       sum(status = 'scheduled') as scheduled_count,
       sum(status = 'failed') as failed_count ,
       sum(status = 'cancelled') as cancelled_count 
from user u inner join
     feedback f
     on f.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.username;
```

Comment: This one generate correct result. Another answer also having same query so I upvoted that also.

Answer (score 1):

I would use conditional aggregation.  MySQL has the following convenient short-hand:

```
select u.username,
       sum(status = 'scheduled') as scheduled_count,
       sum(status = 'failed') as failed_count ,
       sum(status = 'cancelled') as cancelled_count 
from user u inner join
     feedback f
     on f.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.username;
```